# Substitution of the pattern with SED

Tags: text, sed

I have a string

```
ATOM   2448  N   LEU   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           O
```

Here I need to substitute any term in third column (which is always equal to tree capital letters) with NHE.

I try to use

```
sed-e 's/[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]]/NHE/g'
```

but it substitute the  world in the first column also

```
NHEM   2448  N   NHE   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           O
```

how to ask sed to substitute only the word which consist of only the 3 any letters (not with more than 3)?

Thanks!

Comment: `awk '{$4="NHE"; print}' file`?

Comment: @Cyrus, that's a great answer. It will destroy the formatting of the input though. The OP can decide if that's a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+/NHE/4' file
```

Replace the 4th non-empty column with `NHE`

An alternative:

```
sed 's/\S\S*/NHE/4' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3})\<[[:upper:]]{3}\>/\1NHE/' file
```

```
ATOM   2448  N   NHE   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           O
```

Some systems require `-E` instead of `-r`

With GNU sed, you can specify *which* match gets replaced. Here, you want to replace the 4th whitespace-separated word:

```
sed -r 's/[^[:blank:]]+/NHE/4' file
```